# Marketing Cloud - Sender Authentication Package and MX Records

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

After too many hours looking for an explanation in internet and through salesforce support, I don't have a clear picture about how a self-hosted subdomain works after the zone file provided by Salesforce is configured.

Salesforce provides [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_dns_record_maintenance.htm&type=5) description for MXs, CNAMEs and the rest of DNS records included in Zone File for the SAP

- DKIMs, SPFs records are clear for me and it works perfect. We can send emails from Marketing Cloud servers in behalf our subdomain and everything is working perfect.
- MX records: Let provide our example :

```
myselfHosteddomain.com                 IN MX 10        reply.s50.exacttarget.com.

myselfHosteddomain.com                 IN A            161.71.33.242

bounce.myselfHosteddomain.com          IN MX 10        bounce.s50.exacttarget.com.

reply.myselfHosteddomain.com           IN MX 10        reply.s50.exacttarget.com.

leave.myselfHosteddomain.com           IN MX 10        reply.s50.exacttarget.com.
```

**Questions**:

1. The MX records are pointing to ExactTarget servers. If an email is sent from outside of MC to a mailbox on this subdomain (.e.g. examplebox@myselfHosteddomain.com), what happens to this email message?

Please note that RMM would not come into play as this is not a response to a marketing cloud job send. I'm talking about emails being sent to that subdomain configured as SAP in MC.

2. Why do we have more than one MX Record? Theoretically, MX records determine which mail server to use when receiving mails. You can have more than one MX record with same or different priority but as a backup.  Here we have MX records for reply, bounce, leave...